# iterate pandas series with geocoders

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas, google-geocoder

I'm trying to iterate over a dataframe of international addresses in pandas, pass each row to geocoder, parse, and save the results. However, the same results are being returned for every row and I can't figure out why. When I try an example like `3327 WEST 2ND AVE VANCOUVER BC V6R,1` geocoder parses the value as expected but this iteration doesn't work.

```
import geocoder
g = 'GOOGLE_API_KEY'

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    result = geocoder.google(df, key=g)
    df.set_value(i, 'address', result.address)
    df.set_value(i, 'city', result.city)
    df.set_value(i, 'state', result.state)
    df.set_value(i, 'postal', result.postal)
    df.set_value(i, 'country', result.country)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with `geocoder` however looking at your for loop it appears that the same will be returned in every iteration because of this line `result = geocoder.google(df, key=g)` Nothing is changing here between iterations. would `result = geocoder.google(df.loc[i], key=g)` get you closer?

Comment: That solved it. You're the man @johnchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not updating the query in each for loop

try replacing `result = geocoder.google(df, key=g)` with `result = geocoder.google(row, key=g)`

```
import geocoder
g = 'GOOGLE_API_KEY'

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    result = geocoder.google(row, key=g)
    df.set_value(i, 'address', result.address)
    df.set_value(i, 'city', result.city)
    df.set_value(i, 'state', result.state)
    df.set_value(i, 'postal', result.postal)
    df.set_value(i, 'country', result.country)
```